# How to run Mocha Tests from the VSCode test annotation?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I have a Typescript project using Mocha as the test runner. Works like a charm using `npm run test`, works using the VSCode [Mocha Test explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter), but doesn't run from the test annotation: [image: Test annotation]
(for both `Run Test` and `Debug Test`

I get an error

```bash
 node_modules/.bin/mocha test/always.passing.spec.ts --grep="These\stests" 

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/stw/Code/keep-node-sdk/test/always.passing.spec.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:99:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:142:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:91:20)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:263:26)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:179:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:63:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:203:17)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:156:34)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:141:17)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:28)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1163:37)
    at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:428:21)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/vm:105:46)
    at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/modules/esm/utils:87:14)
    at exports.doImport (/Users/stw/Code/keep-node-sdk/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:35:34)
    at formattedImport (/Users/stw/Code/keep-node-sdk/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:9:28)
    at exports.requireOrImport (/Users/stw/Code/keep-node-sdk/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:42:34)
    at exports.loadFilesAsync (/Users/stw/Code/keep-node-sdk/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:100:34)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (/Users/stw/Code/keep-node-sdk/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:447:19)
    at singleRun (/Users/stw/Code/keep-node-sdk/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:15)
    at exports.runMocha (/Users/stw/Code/keep-node-sdk/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:190:10)
    at exports.handler (/Users/stw/Code/keep-node-sdk/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:370:11)
    at /Users/stw/Code/keep-node-sdk/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs:443:71
```

My `mocharc.js`:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  spec: ['test/**/*.spec.ts'],
};
```

The scripts in `package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --pretty --transpile-only src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "postbuild": "npm run test",
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "start": "node .",
    "test": "nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts"
  }
}
```

In the VSCode settings I have

```json
{
  "mochaExplorer.files": "test/**/*.ts",
  "mochaExplorer.require": "ts-node/register",
  "mochaExplorer.logpanel": true,
  "mocha-snippets.function-type": "arrow",
  "testExplorer.onStart": "reset",
  "testExplorer.showOnRun": true,
  "testExplorer.useNativeTesting": true,
  "testExplorer.addToEditorContextMenu": true,
}
```

WHat do I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Your stack trace indicates you're loading ESM dependencies, try installing `ts-node` (edit: It looks like you're already using `ts-node-dev` so you can skip installing it) then adding this to your `.mocharc.json`

```
"loader": "ts-node/esm"
```

And this to your `.vscode/settings.json`

```
"mochaExplorer.nodeArgv": [
    "--loader=ts-node/esm",
    "--no-warnings=ExperimentalWarning",
    "--experimental-specifier-resolution=node"
]
```

Source: https://github.com/hbenl/vscode-mocha-test-adapter/issues/206#issuecomment-1165073354

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the [ts-node documentation](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/recipes/mocha/) had all the answers. There's nothing special needed for mocha in `.vscode/settings`, only a few settings for the testExplorer:

### `.vscode/settings`

```json
{
    "mochaExplorer.logpanel": true,
    "mocha-snippets.function-type": "arrow",
    "testExplorer.onStart": "reset",
    "testExplorer.showOnRun": true,
    "testExplorer.useNativeTesting": true,
    "testExplorer.addToEditorContextMenu": true,
    "testExplorer.codeLens": true
}
```

The settings in the mocharc:

### `.mocharc.js`

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  require: 'ts-node/register',
  loader: 'ts-node/esm',
  spec: ['test/**/*.spec.ts'],
};
```

This also simplifies scripts, e.g. `npm run test` only needs to be:

```bash
nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha
```